# How to save a Colab with all code blocks collapsed by default?

Tags: google-colaboratory

In a Colab I am working on, users are requesting to hide all the code cells by default (upon first open), without having to collapse them manually via the menu. Is this possible?

What I have tried so far: Collapsing all the sections first, then exporting by downloading as an .ipynb file. When re-importing that file into Colab, the sections appear as expanded again, which is not what should be expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that in the .ipynb file, there is a section called "collapsed_sections" which lists the header IDs of cells which are to be collapsed. For some reason, the file I tested on had these set incorrectly. Ensuring they matched the IDs of the actual section IDs in the Colab upon export (gleaned from the URL) solved the issue.

```
  "metadata": {
     "colab": {
       "collapsed_sections": [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start the cell with

```
#@title
```

Then, you can double-click the title. It will hide the code part, but keep the output still visible.

For example

```
#@title My title
greet = "Hello"
print(greet)
```

Double clicking "My title" will still show the output "Hello". Once all the cells containing codes are collapsed, you can save the Colab notebook in Drive or GitHub and they would stay collapsed next time you open the notebook.